# Unity 2D change objects position relatively to a Transform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I am currently working on a unity game that the player is a stickman ragdoll. I created some weapons and they work fine except the method I use to make the player grab a weapon and control it with its hand.
The method I use is to set every frame the weapon position to the player's hand position.
The problem with this method is that the weapon doesn't collide well because it can't move from the player's hand position.

How is it possible to set the weapon's position in the player's hand without changing the weapon's rotation?

Comment: Did you try just making the weapon a child of your character's hand ?

Comment: Yes, the weapon rotated with the player's hand but it didnt move according to the hand's position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that because I had rigidbody on the weapon and on the player's hand it confused the rigidbody method. So I disable the rigidbody on the weapon when the player pick it and this works fine.